# How to remove space in batch

Tags: batch-file

So my batch basically will generate txt file from pdf file that i have in a folder. Then this text file will be analize using batch script to get total fine. but, i cannot fixed the space when echo'ed between TOTAL and $.

**Example text file contains of**

```
                                  Daily Fine Collection

    BRANCH             Staff ID     LAST_NAME            Patron Barcode              DATED                 PAY

***************                                                                                             ------------
TOTAL                                                                                                         $3.00
```

**Once echo'ed, this is the result**

```
02Dec17-Fine.txt : TOTAL                                                                                                         $3.00
04Dec17-Fine.txt : TOTAL                                                                                                          $30.00
05Dec17-Fine.txt : TOTAL                                                                                                           $36.00
06Dec17-Fine.txt : TOTAL                                                                                                          $21.00
07Dec17-Fine.txt : TOTAL                                                                                                        $17.00
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**my batch script**

```
@echo off
setlocal 
for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do "C:\Program Files\xpdf\bin64\pdftotext" -simple "%%i"

for /f "useback delims=: tokens=1-3" %%i in (`findstr /C:"TOTAL" "*.txt"`) do (
        echo %%i : %%j

    )
endlocal
```

Comment: Change `for /f "useback delims=: tokens=1-3"` to `for /f "useback tokens=1-3 delims=: "`, so the _space_ is also part of the set of delimiters...

Comment: Based upon what I think you're trying to do, I would suggest you use `For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr "\<TOTAL\>" "*.txt" 2^>Nul')Do For /F "Tokens=1*" %%C In ("%%B")Do Echo(%%A : %%D`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, some minor changes:

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do "C:\Program Files\xpdf\bin64\pdftotext" -simple "%%i"

for /f "useback tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%i in (`findstr /R /C:"\<TOTAL\>" "*.txt"`) do (
      echo(%%i : %%j %%k
)
```

We just added moved `delims=: "` to before the double quotes, because we want it to capture the space as a delimeter as well ( as mentioned by @aschipfl in comment) we also added token 3 value, `%%k`

I also changed your `findstr` comamnd to use regular expresion to match the exact word `TOTAL` incase you  might have other words containing the word TOTAL. I also removed `setlocal` and `endlocal` because as far as I can see you do not need it here.